# Second WordPress + MySQL on AWS is refusing to connect to MySQL

Tags: wordpress, docker

I had the pleasure to setup WordPress in a docker-compose container for my staging website. Worked like a charm.

Now I am ready to create the production version, so I duplicated the docker-compose file and amended it with different ports and different services names.

However, when I run the lot, the WordPress container keeps rebooting and throwing the error:

```
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
```

I am not really sure why it is not connecting, I am doing the exact same thing as the other docker containers:

```
c63395d420dc        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 10 seconds       0.0.0.0:8003->80/tcp                  foo-wp-prod
d58eeeede519        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        33060/tcp, 127.0.0.1:3310->3306/tcp   foo-wp-db-prod
b6054525bbd9        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 weeks ago         Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp                  foo-wp-staging
e25c3d185152        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 weeks ago         Up 7 seconds        127.0.0.1:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   foo-wp-db-staging
```

I have the docker-compose file here:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db_prod:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: foo-wp-db-prod
    volumes:
      - db_data_prod:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3310:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: -------
      MYSQL_DATABASE: -----
      MYSQL_USER: ------
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: --------

  wordpress_prod:
    depends_on:
      - db_prod
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: foo-wp-prod
    ports:
      - "8003:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db_prod:3310
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: -----
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: -----
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: -----
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/git/prod/wp-content/themes/foo_theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/foo_theme
      - /home/ubuntu/git/prod/wp-content/uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads

volumes:
    db_data_prod:
```

The database is there, the users are there, I can connect remotely to it, so it seems to be the connection between the 2 containers that is not working for this copy of a working setup.

Any chance someone knows what is going on?

**Hosting Environment**

AWS VPS
1 GB RAM
Ubuntu (latest)

Comment: You need to use the internal port number for inter-service connections; for MySQL this is always 3306.  It's the second number in the `ports:` specification, not the first in this case.  If you don't want your database to be visible outside of Docker space it should even work to leave off `ports:` altogether.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you so much for pointing that out. I was under the assumption you had to supply the unique port number on the host. Changing that port number was the only thing I didn't try :-/. If you want, can you repeat your question as an answer, so that I can choose it as the solution? Cheers mate!